# Passing data to a subclass of Seekbar

Tags: android

I have an Activity that contains a Fragent that contains a SeekBar.

I'm aiming for the following behaviour: When the Activity is created, some information is retrieved from the Intent which indicates where on the SeekBar a number of lines should be drawn.

I've created a subclass of SeekBar (I'll call it SubSeekBar) and overridden the onDraw() method to successfully draw lines where I want. The issue is that I can't seem to to pass the information about what lines need to be drawn on SubSeekBar. The LayoutInflater seems to be directly or indirectly responsible for the call to SubSeekBar's constructor.

How should I go about passing the information about the lines from the Activity through to SubSeekBar before it gets drawn (or even after, if that's possible)?

Comment: since your subclassing you can create a custom method. in that you will pass all the information you need and call invalidate to schedule a redraw

Comment: Ah, knowing about invalidate solves everything. Thanks!